# How to use Maven to bump 4th digit of the version?

Tags: java, maven

I have couple of Maven projects, where I would like to bump the fourth version (i.e 1.0.0.**1**). Incrementing version works fine if it's one of the 3 first digits using the below Maven goal.

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set versions:commit
    -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion}
```

How about, if my versioning has four digits? How can I increment my fourth digit?

Comment: The first question is: Why not using three digit as semver suggested etc. ? What is the purpose/information in the 4. digit ?

Comment: What is a build iteration? What kind of information is contained in it?

Comment: To be honest I don't see any value in just increment something...Furthermore are we talking about SNAPSHOT versions or release versions?

Comment: If you have each build to be going to a package manager? (which?) and where is the reason not having a iteration number? Can you explain that more in detail..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your setup you should have `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` in the `pom.xml` and replace the `-SNAPSHOT` path on the CI e.g. with build number or revision number.

Most CI solutions e.g. Jenkins or TeamCity maintain the build number themselves in job configuration. All you have to do is use the correct environment variable e.g. using `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=%BUILD_NUMBER%`.

You can take a look at [Maven Release Plugin: Dead and Buried article](https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html) which suggest a continuous versioning approach.

Comment: @GokulnathKumar the last number in the build is just to distinguish builds, it doesn't really matter what it is. You can replace `-SNAPSHOT` with `<git short hash>-<build number>` or `<git short hash>-<date>`, it makes no difference. Most people don't care what is the exact current version of Chrome or Firefox. Ultimately if your Jenkins goes down you can manually bump the build version number variable, no issue here.